# cordova audio record using org.apache.cordova.media

Tags: android, ios, cordova, file-upload, audio-recording

I am able to capture audio and upload to server successfully using **media.capture**.
But it fails in some devices.
Can anyone help me to use **org.apache.cordova.media** to record audio and upload to server?
I used the below code to upoad the  recorded file.i get always "something went wrong error"

```
function stopRecording() {


    if (my_recorder) 
        my_recorder.stopRecord(); // the file should be moved to "/sdcard/"+mediaRecFile
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);

}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {

    fileSystem.root.getFile("myRecording100.wav", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}
function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        //alert('File URI: ' + fileEntry.toURI());
         var options = new FileUploadOptions();
var ft = new FileTransfer();


var localPath = fileEntry.fullPath;
                var fileURI = fileEntry.toURL();
options.fileKey = "audiofile";
options.mimeType = "audio/wav";
options.fileName = fileURI.substr(fileURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

// upload the file to the server
ft.upload(fileURI, encodeURI("http://xxxxx/version/addaudiofile"), function(r){
console.log(r.response);
var datareg = eval('(' + r.response + ')');
var uid= localStorage.getItem('uid');
var eid= localStorage.getItem('eeid');


var url="http://xxxxxx/version/addaudio";
var ss='data={"uid":"'+uid+'","audio":"'+datareg.audioFileName+'"}';
console.log(ss);


$.ajax({
url:url,
type: 'post',
data:ss,
dataType: 'json',
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
var res=JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest);
var datareg = JSON.parse(res);
//alert(datareg.responseText);
},
success: function (data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
$.mobile.loading( 'hide');


$.mobile.changePage("#audiolist");
return false;
}
});
}, function(error){
alert("Sorry! Something went wrong. Please try again.");
}, options);



}
```

Comment: This much information is not enough. You need to give some code, where is it failing, what kind of error are you getting etc.

Comment: i have posted my code .please check and tell where i make mistake

Comment: define "some devices". Can you get console output from those devices (adb logcat)?

Comment: Oh, and alert the error rather than simply going generic -- chances are good that it would have useful information. `alert(JSON.stringify(error));`

Comment: Couple of other unrelated issues: 1) Never, *ever* use `eval` to parse a response from the server -- security risk! Use `JSON.parse` instead (assuming the response is JSON), wrapped in a `try...catch` block. If the response is not JSON, use the appropriate parser, but never `eval`. 2) Don't build JSON using strings. Build a real JavaScript object (`var o = {"uid":uid, "audio": datareg.audioFileName}`) and then if you need it in a string format use `JSON.stringify(o)`. 3) Before putting into production, switch your uploads and other server communication to use SSL (HTTPS).

Comment: thanks for your answer.was the code i am using to upload recorded voice to server is correct